# Unable to remove and show another ul tag using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am currently having problem displaying a series of `<ul>` tag, but only displaying one at a time and adding a delete button to each `<li>` subtag so as to remove and show another user.

here is my code:

```
<ul id="facebook">
<?php
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users2 LIMIT 10");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
$user_id=$row['id'];
$user_name=$row['name'];
$user_image=$row['profile_pic'];
?>
<li class="myLi" id="list<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
<img src="http://www.hootpile.com/userdata/profile_pic/<?php echo $user_image; ?>" />
<span class="del"><a href="#" class="delete" id="<?php echo user_id; ?>">X</a></span>
<a href="" class="user-title"><?php echo $user_name;?> </a>
<span class="addas">Add as Friend</span>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#facebook').on("click", '.delete', function() {
 var element = $(this);
 var I = element.attr("id");
 $('li#list'+I).fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
});
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to remove the li tag and show another one. i have also added this  `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">` script also in head tag but everthing doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You're triggering a click event on `.delete` element but your element for delete is `.del`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#facebook').on("click", '.del', function() {
 var element = $(this);
 var I = element.attr("id");
 $('li#list'+I).fadeOut('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
});
</script>
```

You are delegating the click event with component of class **`.delete`** , but you dont have any component with that class.

You should be using **`.del`** instead!

Comment: yeah! but still nothing happens.

Comment: Have you checked your console ? for any errors ?

Comment: Are you going to have multiple `li` tags in`ul`??

Comment: yes! there would be multiple li tags.

Comment: I guess than you should be trying to delegate a click event on the `li` tag , rather than the `ul` tag i.e. `<ul id='facebook'>`

Comment: Look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/akykLo26/2/)

Comment: @RahulKapoor : The code worked ?

Comment: yeah,it did somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine you need to wrap it inside of ready function.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){
       jQuery('#facebook').on("click", '.delete', function() {
            var element = jQuery(this);
            var I = element.attr("id");
            jQuery('li#list'+I).fadeOut('slow', function() { jQuery(this).remove();});
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Also call an `event.preventDefault();`